# How to retain the updated value of a global variable in python

Tags: python, global-variables

After I declare a global variable and it is being modified in a function, I want to replace the default value of this global variable to the one modified after the function call. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [so]! Please share a [mcve]!

Answer (score 2):

A common mistake in python is misunderstanding how to use `global` - you don't declare the global in the outside scope but in the inside scope, basically confirming for python that you intend to treat the value as a global.  An example:

```
foo = 1

def set_foo(value):
  global foo
  foo = value

print foo  # prints 1
set_foo(2)
print foo  # prints 2
```

You can see more information in the docs:

https://docs.python.org/release/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#global

Answer (score 0):

Example of using a global variable:

```
def func1():
    global w
    print(w)
    w = 30


w = 10
func1()    # 10
print(w)   # 30
```